# Best way to lookup a value from multiple ranges

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I need to determine what range a value fits in order to determine the appropriate discount. Just trying to determine the best most efficient way to do this in Access (2016). Here is a simplified table:

[image]

My first thought is to loop through a recordset to evaluate each record for >= FROM$ and =< TO$ until a range match is found, then grab the discount rate. Would there be a more efficient way to do this with an SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it is impossible to find the discount for a value such as ***9.999***... it is greater than 9.99 and less than 10 and does not fit inside any of your ranges. I would start by changing your data to:

```
| From | To   | Discount |
|------|------|----------|
| 0    | 10   | 0.05     |
| 10   | 20   | 0.10     |
| 20   | 50   | 0.12     |
| 50   | NULL | 0.13     |
```

And then you could probe the table like so:

```sql
SELECT Discount 
FROM   Discounts
WHERE  (@Value >= [From])
AND    (@Value <  [To] OR [To] IS NULL)
```

Comment: I will test these suggestions and report back. In the meantime I found another example at http://allenbrowne.com/ser-58.html which suggests that you only need to store the starting point of a range which may make sense but had a hard time wrapping my head around the concept. Just wondering if it makes sense to anyone.

Comment: If you use the starting-point-only idea then your from column will look like `0, 10, 20, 50` and the query would be `SELECT TOP 1 Discount ... WHERE @value >= [from] ORDER BY [from] DESC` (I think MSACCESS supports TOP n clause)

Comment: Never used TOP function before. Going to look it up and see if I can make this work. I will report back...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no gaps in the ranges, I find that in many databases the most efficient method is:

```
select t.*,
       (select top 1 d.discount
        from discounts d
        where t.[$] <= d.[from$]  -- the $ is for whatever column name you actually use
        order by d.[from$] desc
       ) as discount
from t;
```

(Note that this ignores `to$`.)

In particular, this should be able to take advantage of an index on `discounts(from$, discount)`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `where t.[$] >= d.[from$]`?

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `BETWEEN` here:

```
SELECT
    MAX(IIF(price BETWEEN FROM$ AND TO$, Discount, NULL)) AS Discount
FROM yourTable;
```

We might more typically expect that your table of discounts would store information for multiple groups, e.g. products.  In that case, we could write:

```
SELECT
    product,
    MAX(IIF(price BETWEEN FROM$ AND TO$, Discount, NULL)) AS Discount
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    product;
```